# Python Error: “ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack”

Tags: arcpy, cursor, array, valueerror

Can someone help me figure out what is not working in this piece of code:

```
import arcpy
import fileinput
import os
import string

from arcpy import env

env.workspace = "C:/EsriPress/Python/Data/Exercise08"
env.overwriteOutput = True
outpath = "C:/EsriPress/Python/Data/Exercise08"
newfc = "Results/newpolyline.shp"
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(outpath, newfc, "Polyline")

infile = "C:/EsriPress/Python/Data/Exercise08/coordinates.txt"

cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(newfc, ["SHAPE@"])
array = arcpy.Array()

for line in fileinput.input(infile):
    ID, X, Y = string.split(line, " ")
    array.add(arcpy.Point(X,Y))
cursor.insertRow([arcpy.Polyline(array)])
fileinput.close()
del cursor
```

I looked up some other questions/responses related to this error and they mention that perhaps the text file being read is not formatted correctly. Each line in my text file has an object ID, and an X & Y coordinates, with only one space in between each field (also, there is no extra line or space after the final object).

I'm wondering what else can be giving me this error.

Comment: Does your newfc have 3d coordinates? Try setting arcpy.env.outputZFlag = "disabled" and arcpy.env.outputMFlag = "disabled" to temporarily assert no Z/M values in created feature classes. The other thing you might try is array.add(arcpy.Point(float(X),float(Y))), python isn't strong typed but there might be something internal that doesn't like strings.

Comment: Insert , between ] and )

Comment: @MichaelStimson I tried adding the env settings , as well as using the float function on the X and Y variables as you suggests.  Unfortunately I am still receiving the same value error message.

Comment: @Felix You're saying I should try inserting a comma (,) in between the right bracket   ]  and parentheses ) ? Am I reading that correctly?  If so, which part of the code should I insert the comma ?

Comment: pLine= arcpy.Polyline(array); cursor.insertRow((pLine,))

Comment: Is there only one coordinate in the file? I'm not sure about for line in fileinput.. I find it easier to just open the file and then read line by line. Can you post a section of the file? The first few lines should be ok. I can see you're doing an exercise so I don't want to go too far away from what the point of this is...

Comment: @MichaelStimson


Hi Michael, so first of all here is a screen shot of the text file I'm working with. https://imgur.com/wPiYslY 
(Also, I tried saving the text file with different encoding options, but that did not seem to do the trick)

As for your first suggestion about adding the print line function to the for loop...I tried it and it printed the first line and stopped there. 

Secondly, I felt up to the challenge of trying the try: except:  
My results showed the first line printed normally , but the subsequent lines were also printed but with the Except message printed.

Comment: Have you tried switching file readers to the builtin open https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open ? like the 2nd answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27577435/read-txt-file-line-by-line-in-python I have not used the fileinput module, probably because the builtin works perfectly for me. That it reads the first line and bails is suspicious, there could be a non-printing character problem manifest. I'll put some try/excepts into the answer to show how they can be used.

Comment: @MichaelStimson

Thanks for the help , I tried your edits and the feature was created this time around.  So could it have been the fileinput module that was causing this error to pop up?
In any case, it seems that there is no reason for me to use that module since the built-in file opening function works , correct?

Comment: I would opt for the builtin in this case because the fileinput module offers no real benefit.. other file readers like csv https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html or xml https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.html# give some advantage over the builtin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a minimum of modification to your code:

```
array = arcpy.Array()

with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(newfc, "SHAPE@") as cursor:
    with open(infile,'r') as inHand:
        for line in inHand:
                ID, X, Y = line.split(" ")
                Xco = float(X)
                Yco = float(Y)
                array.add(arcpy.Point(Xco,Yco))

    cursor.insertRow([arcpy.Polyline(array)])
```

Works for me. There could be a lock, something wrong with your text file or your implementation of `fileinput`, but reading [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) it seems that your implementation is correct therefore it seems the likely culprit is your text file or a persistent lock on the shapefile.

To release an existing lock, evidenced by a lock file (sr.lock, wr.lock etc) present with the shapefile, close all Esri products and hopefully it will disappear, if not, you might need to restart your computer (being that severe would be a rare event).

To try to find garbage in the text file try printing the line (add print(line) in your code on the line right after `for line in..`) so that when it crashes out you know which line caused the error and try to guess why.

Normally I'd put in a `try: except:` block on the next line after `for line in inHand:` because I don't trust text files to have 3 (or more) elements, the latter two being numeric, *all the time* regardless of how sure the creator of the file is - I've been burnt too may times by garbage in a text file to be complacent about it:

```
with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(newfc, "SHAPE@") as cursor:
    with open(infile,'r') as inHand:
        for line in inHand:
            LineAllGood = True
            try:
                ID, X, Y = line.split(" ")
            except:
                LineAllGood = False # don't do the next step.
                arcpy.AddWarning('Line {} produces an error in splitting'.format(line))

            if LineAllGood: # The splitting worked, now try to float both
                try:
                    Xco = float(X)
                    Yco = float(Y)
                    array.add(arcpy.Point(Xco,Yco))
                except:
                    arcpy.AddWarning('Conversion error X {} or Y {} not a float'.format(X,Y))

    cursor.insertRow([arcpy.Polyline(array)])
```